# how to create logic to run python code in self made code editor properly like python shell

Tags: python, function, tkinter, input, ide

I have create run function to run python script but when i use input() code it shows error
error is

```
Enter any numberTraceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\USER\Downloads\N1.py", line 1, in <module>

    a = int(input("Enter any number"))

EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

```
            command = f"python {self.file}"
            run_file = subprocess.Popen(command, stdin=subprocess.PIPE,stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
            Output, error = run_file.communicate()
            self.text.output_area.insert(END,f"{self.file}>>\n")
            self.text.output_area.insert(END,Output)
            self.text.output_area.insert(END,error)
```

what modification I have to do in my run function ?????

Comment: What exactly you want to achieve?

Comment: I edit the post again please read

Comment: Use try and except method

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/handling-eoferror-exception-in-python/#:~:text=EOFError%20is%20raised%20when%20one,input%20in%20the%20input%20box.

Comment: Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Sorry to distrub you sir but i am facing this error '''EOF when reading a line'''

Comment: i have created my own ide in which i am facing this problem

Comment: @typedecker Sir,i am new on stackoverflow sorry, i will improve myself

Comment: @Anmol No need to say sorry! Everyone is new at start :D, my intention behind posting that link was to make sure you can contribute in an even better way in the future. Thanks!